# Can SAPI be redistributed in a WINE wrapper?

Tags: sapi

I have a Windows program which a handful of Mac users are asking for. I don't have the skill or incentive to make a dedicated Mac version. Is it allowable to redistribute my software in a Wine wrapper when it relies on the SAPI engine?

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  If you're using SAPI components that come as part of a separately redistributable package (e.g., Microsoft Speech Runtime 11), those components have a [specific license](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=224130) that allows for 3rd party redistribution.   If you're using SAPI components that are distributed as part of the operating system (e.g., SAPI 5.4 & the desktop SR and TTS engines), then no, you're not allowed to redistribute them.